# Mutating ndb repeated property

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have two classes, `Department` and `Employee`. `Department` has a property declared as

`employees = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=ClassB, repeated=True)`

The problem is,when i delete the entity whose key is held in the `employees` list, the entity is deleted in the `Employee` datastore, but the list in `Department` datastore remains the same (with the key of the deleted employee still in it).

How do i make sure that when the `Employee` is deleted, all references to it in the `Department` datastore is deleted as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way to do this.I created a method in `class A (Department)` like this

```
def deleteEmployee(self, employee):
    employee_to_delete = employee.key
    if employee_to_delete in self.employees:
        idx=self.employees.index(employee_to_delete)
        del self.employees[idx]
        self.put()
```

and then from the Handler(could also be another method somewhere) where i am deleting the key from the list,i did something like this

```
class DeleteEmployeeHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def post(self):
    employee_name = self.request.get('employee_name')
    employee=Employee.get_by_id(employee_name)
    emp_dept=employee.department
    dept=Department.get_or_insert(emp_dept)
    dept.deleteEmployee(employee)  #delete employee key from list
    employee.key.delete()  #then finally delete employee entity
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no automatic way of doing this.

You need to perform queries for all types that could hold the key and then delete them in code.

If there could be a lot and/or it could take a long time you might want to consider using a task.

Comment: Yes,I know I will have to do this programmatically but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do this.There is on deleting entities but not on deleting values from a list.Be it a key or just a String. The official documentation just says "When updating a repeated property, you can either assign it a new list or mutate the existing list in place. When you assign a new list, the types of the list items are validated immediately."

Comment: This is python.  It is just a list.  Use standard list methods to remove or re-assign the contents of the list such as `pop()` .  I suggest you read the python doc's on lists.

Comment: Okay.Thanks.I'll do just that.